# Visual Studio не видит поле C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio не видит и не подсвечивает поле. Но в окошке с просмотрами элементов файла он есть. На всякий случай скину код

```
public class Constants
{
    public static Dictionary<String, Double> constants = new Dictionary<string, double>(2);
    constants.Add("PI", Math.PI);
}
```

Comment: этот код, что вы показываете, невалиден и не будет компилироваться.

Answer (score 1):

Можете так попробывать:

```
public class Constants
{
    public Dictionary<String, Double> constants = new Dictionary<String, Double>();
    public void SetPi() => constants.Add("PI", Math.PI);
}

public class Program
{
    private static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Constants constant = new Constants();
        constant.SetPi();

        Console.WriteLine(constant.constants["PI"]);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Учитывая замечания @tym32167, можно сделать так:

```
public class Constants
{
    public static Dictionary<String, Double> constants = new Dictionary<String, Double>
    {
        { "PI", Math.PI }
    };
}

public class Program
{
    private static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Constants.constants["PI"]);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Начиная с C# 6.0 доступен также еще один способ инициализации:

```
public class Constants
{
    public static Dictionary<String, Double> constants = new Dictionary<String, Double>
    {
        ["PI"] = Math.PI
    };
}
```

Comment: Зачем этот метод? Поле то публичное

Comment: @tym32167, чтоб записать значение в словарь

Comment: ну я в том смысле, что клиент класса это сможет сделать и без метода )

Comment: @tym32167, я знаю, мне просто показалось что это тоже приемлемо

Comment: приемлемо конечно, я просто не понял вашей мотивации. Теперь понял, вопрос закрыт

Comment: @tym32167, поправил ответ)